# R - Gsub return first match

Tags: regex, r

I want to extract the 12 and the 0 from the test vector. Every time I try it would either give me 120 or 12:0

```
TestVector <- c("12:0")
gsub("\\b[:numeric:]*",replacement = "\\1", x = TestVector, fixed = F)
```

What can I use to extract the 12 and the 0. Can we just have one where I just extract the 12 so I can change it to extract the 0. Can we do this exclusively with gsub?

Comment: And what's wrong with simple `\d+` ? Check this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ7sP0/1)

Comment: I don't know, can you give an example?

Comment: There will likely be a more concise way, however, `unlist(regmatches(TestVector, gregexpr('\\(?[0-9, .]+', TestVector)))`

Comment: `gsub("\\b(\\d+):(\\d+)?\\b",replacement = "\\1  \\2", x = TestVector, fixed = F)`

Comment: @rock321987, this worked perfectly, Put this as the answer, maybe with an explanation of the regex

Comment: still, question is not clear to me..is the string always in `xx:yy` format?

Comment: @rock321987 yes, this is the format, but if say I have x:yy or xx:y

Comment: then also it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
gsub("\\b(\\d+):(\\d+)\\b",replacement = "\\1 \\2", x = TestVector, fixed = F)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\\b #Word boundary
  (\\d+) #Find all digits before :
   :  #Match literally colon
  (\\d+) #Find all digits after :
\\b #Word boundary
```

I think there is no named class as `[:numeric:]` in `R` till I know, but it has named class `[[:digit:]]`. You can use it as

```
gsub("\\b([[:digit:]]+):([[:digit:]]+)\\b",replacement = "\\1  \\2", x = TestVector)
```

As suggested by [rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr), a much simpler and intuitive way to do it would be to just simply replace `:` with `space`

```
gsub(":",replacement = " ", x = TestVector, fixed = F)
```

Answer (score 5):

One option, which doesn't involve using explicit regular expressions, would be to use `strsplit()` and split the timestamp on the colon:

```
TestVector <- c("12:0")
parts <- unlist(strsplit(TestVector, ":")))
> parts[1]
[1] "12"
> parts[2]
[1] "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `scan` from `base R`

```
 scan(text=TestVector, sep=":", what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
 #[1] 12  0
```

---

or with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(TestVector, "[^:]+")[[1]]
```